# Не помещается нормально с помощью цикла массивы в массив

Tags: php

Собственно, есть массив

> *array(1,1,2,3);* - пример(код ниже)

И в этот же массив, не уходя куда-то вглубь помещаются еще массивы с помощью цикла.При попытке вывести print_r или var_dump : *Выводится только Array(пару раз)*

**Код**:

```
$mcsv = array(
    'Имя',
    'Фамилия',
    'ID',
    'Пол',
    'День Рождения',
);

for ($i = 0; $i < $c = 4; $i++) { 
    $mcsv .= array("1",);
}

print_r($mcsv);
```

Отчет **error_repoting()**

> Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\OpenServer\domains\Parser\index.php on line 19 << Это повторяется пару тысяч раз.

Comment: `$mcsv[] = array( "1" );`

Comment: $mcsv .= array() ... 
это вам не строка =)

Comment: Из вашего вопроса совершенно не ясно куда вы хотите поместить массив.

Comment: @Visman  *в этот же массив, не уходя куда-то вглубь* :)

Comment: Спасибо.Забыл что .= вообще не для такого и есть []

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо `$mcsv .= array("1");` сделайте:

```
$mcsv[] = array('1');

//или

array_push($mcsv, array('1'));
```

P.S. И оформляйте код аккуратно. У вас даже в этом маленьком кусочке есть опечатки.

Comment: А вот меня смущает, что вы 5 раз хотите добавить в массив элемент со значением '1' ;)

Comment: @Visman сработает, не с ключом же  :)

Comment: @Visman это не элемент со значением 1, это массив, состоящий из одного элемента. :) Я лишь исправил явный косяк автора вопроса. За логикой программы стоит обращаться к нему. :)

Comment: @Дмитрий, а насчет опечаток, вы не правы. Код вполне рабочий, хотя форматирование и было отвратительным :-)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev до ваших правок в цикле была запись `$i < $ c = 4` (с пробелом) - это бы сработало?

Comment: Это был черновой вариант.Там особо не размышлял как и что написать.Просто нужно было что-то закинуть в массивы.Но код рабочий. @Дмитрий $i < $ c = 4 работает

Comment: Ладно-ладно, не надо меня всем сообществом бить.

Comment: @Дмитрий, да, вы правы. Я на автомате поправил, даже не заметив :)